# PhantomJs and wappalyzer

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to create a script for phantomjs that would load wappalyzer. But I always get error Can't find variable :wappalyzer

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.google.com', function () {

page.injectJs('wappalyzer/wappalyzer.js');
page.injectJs('wappalyzer/wappalyzer/apps.js');
page.injectJs('wappalyzer/wappalyzer/driver.js');

page.evaluate(function(pageContent){
      var env = [];
      for(var env_var in window) { 
        if ( window.hasOwnProperty(env_var)) {
          env.push(env_var);
        } 
      }
      console.log(pageContent.w);
      wappalyzer.analyze("www.prestitiinpdap.it", "http://www.prestitiinpdap.it", {
        html: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML,
        env: env
      });

      var apps = [];
      wappalyzer.detected["http://www.prestitiinpdap.it"].map(function(app) {
        if ( wappalyzer.apps[app] ) {
          apps.push(app);
        }
      });
      console.log(apps);


});

page.render('google.png');
phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: The wappalyzer variables you are using is in phantom's scope. And not in the pages scope. These two scopes are different.

Comment: So what is the correct way to access to wappalyzer?

Comment: @Pallab do you have any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well on my Mac. You need to create hard links as suggested by the author itself on a [github issue](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/issues/1553).

From the Wappalyzer directory run:

```
./bin/links .
```